# Write a function called "remove_numbers_larger_than" in mixed dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a number and an dictionary, "remove_numbers_larger_than" removes any keys whose values are numbers greater than the given number. Return the modified dictionary.

```
inp = {'a': 8, 'b': 2, 'c': 'montana'}

remove_numbers_larger_than(5, inp)

print(inp) # --> {'b': 2, 'c': 'montana'}
```

My issue is I do not know how to do this with a string in the inp dictionary.

```
def remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if type(v) == str:
            continue 
        if type(v) == int and v > number:
            del[k]
        
    return dictionary
```

This is what I have so far, and I am not sure if I am going in the right direction. Thanks for any help in my learning process.

Comment: You could just use `try`; if making the `>` comparison fails (for whatever reason), just `catch` and `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to write the appropriate conditions according to the `dtype`. Here's a way using a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k:v for k,v in inp.items() if not (isinstance(v, int) and (v>5))}
# {'b': 2, 'c': 'montana'}
```

Which is equivalent to the following `for` loop:

```
d = dict()
for k,v in inp.items():
    if not (isinstance(v, int) and (v>5)):
        d[k] = v
```

Comment: Wouldn't this toss everything that wasn't an `int` or `str`?

Comment: shouldn't this be enough ``if not(isinstance(v, int) and v > 5)`` ?

Comment: Yes I think that would be better

Comment: Appreciate it :) @Sushanth and scott

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```py
dic = {'a': 8, 'b': 2, 'c': 'montana'}
def remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary):
    return {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if not (isinstance(value, int) and value > number)}
print(remove_numbers_larger_than(2, dic))
# output: {'b': 2, 'c': 'montana'}
```

And the following is the same but written more understandable:

```py
def remove_numbers_larger_than(number, dictionary):
    newDict = {}

    # looping over the keys and values of the dictionary
    for key, value in dictionary.items():

        # checking if 1st the value is an integer and if so we secondly check if it is higher than 'number'
        # note that we put both checks into braces, because of the "not" statement.
        # if we wouln't put it into braces the "not" would only get applied to the first statemtent,
        # but we want it to apply to the result of both checks together
        if not (isinstance(value, int) and value > number):
            newDict[key] = value

    return newDict
print(remove_numbers_larger_than(2, dic))
# output: {'b': 2, 'c': 'montana'}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Please review your answer, it looks like it's duplicate of @yatu's answer.

Comment: Since his answer got edited, it is a duplicate now but wasn't before

Comment: Could you please write this in a more expanded format? This did solve my problem, so thank you for that. I am still somewhat new to python and programming, and I am not very familiar with comprehensions yet. Seeing code in both formats is helping me leanr comprehensions though. Thanks again!

Comment: just a moment @user13682040